# I want to calculate leaves b/w two dates where status is approved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
 def calculate_availed_leave
  if self.saved_change_to_status? && self.status == "Approved"
   leave_start_date = self.start_date
   leave_end_date = self.end_date
   leave_date = []
   taken_leaves = Leave.includes(:employee).where(status: "Approved" ).where(start_date:leave_start_date..leave_end_date)
   taken_leaves.each do |leave|
     leave_date =   leave.end_date - leave.start_date  
   end
  availed_leaves = self.employee.allowed_leaves - leave_date
  self.employee.update(availed_leaves: availed_leaves)
end
```

I want to calculate leaves b/w two dates where status is approved  but did not know how i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with your code:

- `taken_leaves` isn't scoped to a single employee: you're iterating across leaves for *all* employees
- `leave_date` is being overwritten multiple times. The initial value (`[]`) isn't ever used, nor are any of the values set in the `each` block (until the last one). That value is then used to update `employee.availed_leaves`.

In short, you're updating an employee's `availed_leave` by looking at only one leave (which potentially belongs to another employee), rather than than looking at all leaves belonging to just that employee.

Assuming you have `has_many :leaves` in your `Employee` model definition, you can rewrite this code like so:

```rb
leave_taken = employee.leaves.
  select('leaves.*, (leaves.end_date - leaves.start_date) AS duration').
  where(status: 'Approved', start_date: start_date..end_date)

available_leaves = employee.allowed_leaves - leave_taken.sum(:duration)
```

Note: unless you're overwriting the attributes on your `Leave` model to have side effects, you don't need all the `self.`s you have in your code currently.